# Can a strong electric field generate an electric current within a closed loop of wire?

Tags: voltage, current, dc, closed-loop

I would like to know if an electric current can be generated in a closed loop of wire by using a strong electric field to circulate the free electrons within the closed loop of wire.

Say that you have a high voltage DC power supply, one that can generate 100 kV, and this will be used to create a strong electric field between the electrodes that will be connected to it. These two electrodes will need to be covered with insulation, such as mica, so no electric current can flow between them, yet the mica will allow the electrodes' electric charges to flow through it.

I believe that in order for free electrons to circulate through a closed loop of wire, they need to be propelled by the electric field, yet at the same time they cannot be blocked by or attracted to the electrical charges of the two electrodes outside of the electric field.

In order to accomplish this, the wire's insulation will need to be a material with a very high dielectric constant. I think an ideal material to use would be calcium copper titanate, which has a dielectric constant/relative permittivity of 250,000 (per Wikipedia). Whether this material can block an electrical charge of 100 kV, I really don't know since I am not an electrical engineer and have a limited knowledge of electricity.

To help illustrate how these electrodes from the HV DC power supply would generate electricity in a closed loop of wire, I have created the following drawing. (This drawing is showing a cross-sectional view, and the two electrodes have holes in the middle of them so the wire can pass through them.)

[image]

Can a strong electric field generate an electric current within a closed loop of wire?

Comment: This is an odd one, but I think a standard approach would be to draw the electric field lines; note that an electric field is zero *within* a conductor, so the only place where interactions could happen is on the surface. The other question to ask is, where does the energy to circulate the electrons come from? This smells of perpetual motion machine.

Comment: @pjc50, I believe that if the electrons on the surface are pushed in one direction, this should push all the electrons within the wire, but I don't know if this would be the case. Also, the energy would be coming from the HV DC power supply.

Comment: Well, if instead of a wire you have an hollow tube with magnets to steer the electrons along its path... you have made yourself a particle accelerator! The key here is that the energy imparted by the field is not lost along the path (if not for some radiation due to acceleration) and you can have a current. But if you fill the tube with atoms, even if it's only a gas, your energy will be lost in collisions before the electrons can complete the circuit and be accelerated again.

Comment: Check out eddy current brakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electrons will be attracted to the +... and they'll stay as close to the + as possible (i.e. at the point with the highest electric potential). There *is* a point *somewhere* with the highest electric potential, and that's where they'll go. They won't circulate.

This is a lot like trying to make a perpetual motion machine with shielded magnets, except you're doing it with electric charges instead.

In this scenario, all of the electric field lines go from low potential areas to high potential areas. You can't create loops in the electric field unless you have a changing magnetic field.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a perpetual motion machine, I just want to know if an electric current would flow through the wire.

Comment: @user255577 If an electric current would flow through the wire that would be perpetual motion, wouldn't it? Because it would never stop flowing.

Comment: @ user253751, no, because it would stop flowing once you shut off the HV DC power supply.

Comment: @user255577 So it would use energy from the HV DC power supply... If there's no current through the HV DC power supply, then it's not using energy. If there *is* current, where is it going?

Comment: @ user253751, I'm not sure I understand you. The HV DC power supply would be plugged into an electrical outlet in my house.

Comment: @user255577 Electrical power is voltage times current. We have the voltage (it's in your drawing). If the loopy thing is using power from the HV DC power supply, then there is also a current involved. Where is the current? (It's not the electrons going around in the loop, because those aren't connected to the supply)

Comment: You could disconnect the supply and the 100kV plate *stays* at 100kV until something causes it to discharge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113794/discussion-between-user255577-and-user253751).